# amadeus api : offer pricing call produces 400 - type needed

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, amadeus

I'm calling the offer price API and receiving a 400 with a "type needed" message.

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.amadeus.exceptions.ClientException: [400]
> type needed

The call via postman API succeeds (https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing), so I take the body used in that, and send it via java API call where I receive the error.

This is on test env.

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/pricing

The body sent (which is taken from the working postman example):

```
{
  "type": "flight-offer",
  "id": "1",
  "source": "GDS",
  "instantTicketingRequired": false,
  "nonHomogeneous": false,
  "oneWay": false,
  "lastTicketingDate": "2022-11-01",
  "numberOfBookableSeats": 9,
  "itineraries": [
    {
      "duration": "PT1H20M",
      "segments": [
        {
          "departure": {
            "iataCode": "LHR",
            "terminal": "4",
            "at": "2022-11-01T06:25:00"
          },
          "arrival": {
            "iataCode": "CDG",
            "terminal": "2E",
            "at": "2022-11-01T08:45:00"
          },
          "carrierCode": "AF",
          "number": "1381",
          "aircraft": {
            "code": "320"
          },
          "operating": {
            "carrierCode": "AF"
          },
          "duration": "PT1H20M",
          "id": "1",
          "numberOfStops": 0,
          "blacklistedInEU": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "duration": "PT1H20M",
      "segments": [
        {
          "departure": {
            "iataCode": "CDG",
            "terminal": "2E",
            "at": "2022-11-05T18:00:00"
          },
          "arrival": {
            "iataCode": "LHR",
            "terminal": "4",
            "at": "2022-11-05T18:20:00"
          },
          "carrierCode": "AF",
          "number": "1180",
          "aircraft": {
            "code": "319"
          },
          "operating": {
            "carrierCode": "AF"
          },
          "duration": "PT1H20M",
          "id": "6",
          "numberOfStops": 0,
          "blacklistedInEU": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "price": {
    "currency": "EUR",
    "total": "255.30",
    "base": "48.00",
    "fees": [
      {
        "amount": "0.00",
        "type": "SUPPLIER"
      },
      {
        "amount": "0.00",
        "type": "TICKETING"
      }
    ],
    "grandTotal": "255.30",
    "additionalServices": [
      {
        "amount": "50.00",
        "type": "CHECKED_BAGS"
      }
    ]
  },
  "pricingOptions": {
    "fareType": [
      "PUBLISHED"
    ],
    "includedCheckedBagsOnly": false
  },
  "validatingAirlineCodes": [
    "AF"
  ],
  "travelerPricings": [
    {
      "travelerId": "1",
      "fareOption": "STANDARD",
      "travelerType": "ADULT",
      "price": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "total": "127.65",
        "base": "24.00"
      },
      "fareDetailsBySegment": [
        {
          "segmentId": "1",
          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
          "fareBasis": "GS50OALG",
          "brandedFare": "LIGHT2",
          "class": "G",
          "includedCheckedBags": {
            "quantity": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "segmentId": "6",
          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
          "fareBasis": "GS50OALG",
          "brandedFare": "LIGHT2",
          "class": "G",
          "includedCheckedBags": {
            "quantity": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "travelerId": "2",
      "fareOption": "STANDARD",
      "travelerType": "ADULT",
      "price": {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "total": "127.65",
        "base": "24.00"
      },
      "fareDetailsBySegment": [
        {
          "segmentId": "1",
          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
          "fareBasis": "GS50OALG",
          "brandedFare": "LIGHT2",
          "class": "G",
          "includedCheckedBags": {
            "quantity": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "segmentId": "6",
          "cabin": "ECONOMY",
          "fareBasis": "GS50OALG",
          "brandedFare": "LIGHT2",
          "class": "G",
          "includedCheckedBags": {
            "quantity": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Java API call I make couldn't be simpler:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amadeus/amadeus-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amadeus</groupId>
            <artifactId>amadeus-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
    @PostMapping("/confirm")
    public ResponseEntity<FlightPrice> confirm(@RequestBody FlightOfferSearch search) throws ResponseException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(amadeusConnector.confirm(search));
    }
```

```
    public FlightPrice confirm(FlightOfferSearch offer) throws ResponseException {
        return amadeus.shopping.flightOffersSearch.pricing.post(offer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue caused by *Amadeus Java SDK*, I just created a [PR](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java/pull/182) for this issue which has been merged, thus I believe a new patched version will be released soon.

Additionally, if you wonder what the problem exact is, you can take a look at the following:

As you said in the problem, when you use string body to call this API, it works.
But when you use the `offer` object to call, it fails.

In that case, we can try to compare the differences between `offer` and the string you used before.

If you enable Amadeus Java SDK `debug` mode, then reproduce this issue again, you will see the log information which describes this error very clearly

```
Jul 22, 2022 11:06:56 AM com.amadeus.HTTPClient log
INFO: Response(statusCode=400, parsed=true, result={"errors":[{"code":32171,"title":"MANDATORY DATA MISSING","detail":"type needed","source":{"pointer":"/data/flightOffers[0]/price/additionalServices[0]/type"},"status":400}]}`,...)
```

The information above means the `offer` object we passed is missing the
`type` data.

Thus, we need to add the `type` property into the `resource.FlightOfferSearch.Price.AdditionalService` resource model class.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick fix - I found the bug last night and was going to raise PR today. I noticed the property wasn't missing from FlightOfferSearch class but had the wrong name - ie didn't match the JSON schema.
Again, thank you!